# how to get strut <html:select> multiple value from jsp in java script

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and struts.  I have an legacy front end uses jsp, javascript, strut.  Application has a jsp which builds a list which is currently single select.  Now I have a request to change it to multiple select.   I have added multiple option to .   But I am not able get the multiple values selected in my javascript.  Here is the part of the code.

```
<html:html>
    <form name="reimport" action = ""/>
        <td>
            <div>
                <%if("GWSD".equals(request.getSession().getAttribute("Export")))
                { %>
                    <html:select property="tmI" multiple="true" size="8" value=" " >
                    <%
                    String tmId = "";     
                    String tmName = "";
                    String dmId = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < tmSize; i++) {
                        TargetTMItemOutBean item = (TargetTMOutBean)outBean.getTmList().get(i);
                        tmId = item.getTMId();
                        boolean isDisabledFound = false;
                        for (int j=0; j < dmSize && !isDisabledFound; j++) {
                            DisableOutBean dItem = (DisableOutBean)outBean.getDMList().get(j);
                            dmId = dItem.getDMD();
                            if (StringUtils.equals(tmId, dmId)) {
                                isDisabledFound = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!isDisabledFound) {
                            tmName = tmId + " - " + item.getTMName();
                        %>
                        <html:option key="<%=tmId%>" value="<%=tmName%>"/>
                        <%
                        }
                    }     
                    %>
                    </html:select>&nbsp;   
                <%}
           %>
           </div>
        </td>
    </form>
</html:html>
```

Java script:

```
function checkReImport(tabType, cntAtributSelected, premessage, message){
  if(document.reimport.tmI != null){
   var selected = document.reimport.tmI;
   opener.document.RBGetDataInBean.tMI.value=selected;
  }
```

I could select multiple values from list.  But in the java script I get only one. Any help is very much appreciated.